# Encrypting and decrypting data with a symmetric key

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-kms

I have encrypted file inside the bucket in storage and now I am decrypting that file in my application using java programming like below-

```
public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] ciphertext) throws Exception {
    DecryptResponse response = null;
    try {
        KeyManagementServiceClient client = KeyManagementServiceClient.create() ;
        String resourceName = CryptoKeyName.format(projectId, locationId, keyRingId, cryptoKeyId);
    // Decrypt the ciphertext with Cloud KMS.
         response = client.decrypt(resourceName, ByteString.copyFrom(ciphertext));
```

But in this program I am using **projectId, locationId, keyRingId , cryptoKeyId** to decrypt.

Is there any possibility to decrypt that file in my application without using  `locationId`, `keyRingId` and `cryptoKeyId` through default app engine service account ?

Comment: What do you mean by *through default app engine service account*? Your application is run with this service account? You will always need to include `projectId`, `locationId`, `keyRingId` and `cryptoKeyId` in your code to decrypt, otherwise, how can the application find itself where the key is located?

Comment: Do you want to use your own service account and not the AppEngine default one. Am I right?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you concerned about the security of specifying `projectId`, etc in your code or are you looking for a shortcut to specify the KMS key? Edit your question with more details on what you want to do.